# LIRC receiver problem after kernel update

Tags: pi-3, kernel, lirc

I recently updated my raspberry pi 3 using `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` . During the process rpi kernel got updated.

```
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.42-v7+ #1219 SMP Tue May 14 21:20:58 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

After a reboot, IR receiver stopped working which got fixed by changing
`dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_in_pin=23,gpio_out_pin=22`
to `dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=23 dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=22`.

Now IR receiver is working when I test using `sudo mode2 -d /dev/lirc0`, it shows pulses & spaces stream. 
But LIRC does not seem to be working as irw shows no output and python-lirc does not work too. When I press remote button , this message is shown in dmesg log :

`[ 1015.407357] rc rc0: two consecutive events of type space`

How to make lirc work again with ir receiver ?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=236240

Comment: @CoderMike I would make it an answer.